# After upgrading to 18.10 why are files/nautilus bookmark icons in the sidebar traced in brown?

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10

Can anyone tell me why in 18.10, using gnome under xorg,there is a brown colour around the bookmarks in nautilus? It's only the bookmark icons, other sidebar icons are fine.

[image]

It also doesn't matter what theme I use

[image]

Comment: It depends on your theme. The theme that you use may very well have got an upgrade with 18.10.

Comment: I use standard adwatia, and whatever I change the theme to the icons look the same (the sidebar bookmark folders)